# Ignore braces as special characters in userEvent.type

Tags: testing-library, user-event

I'm using `@testing-library/user-event` to try to type in a text box containing JSON. Sadly, it appears that because `{` is a special character in the string, I get an error when running this:

```js
await userEvent.type(input, '{ "id": 1, "name": "William" }');
```

> Expected repeat modifier or release modifier or "}" but found """ in "{ "id": 1, "name": "William" }"

I don't see any options available to tell `user-event` to treat text literally. Am I missing this in the documentation, or am I SOL using this technique?

Answer (score 2):

After some source diving, I found that doubling up the brackets works.

```js
await userEvent.type(input, '{{ "id": 1, "name": "William" }');
```